# $f:\mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^4}$ knowing $\ker(f) \neq \{0\}$, an eigenspace and an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine a diagonalizable homomorphism $f$ such that $\ker(f) \neq \{0\}$, an eigenspace is $V=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R^4} : x-y=x+z-t=0\}$
and an eigenvalue is $\lambda=4$ (It is not specified that $4$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $V$).

(I would write down my thoughts if I had any)

Answer (score 0):

$V$ is a $2$ dimensional space, which means it has two basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$.

We can then expand $\{v_1, v_2\}$ into a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ which is $\{v_1,v_2, v_3, v_4\}$

Then, we know that $f$ maps $v_1$ to $4v_1$ and $v_2$ to $4v_2$. We also know $f$ needs a vecotr in it's kernel, so we can decide $f$ maps $v_3$ and $v_4$ to $0$ (thus, $v_3$ and $v_4$ become elements of $\ker f$

So, in the basis $\{v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4\}$, the matrix of $f$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\ 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Now, fill in the gaps:

- Find $v_i$
- Transform the matrix of $f$ to the standard basis.

Comment: I think the standard basis is \begin{bmatrix}0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\ 0&0&4&0\\0&1&4&0\end{bmatrix}, I'm not sure though.
I calculated $f(e_1,...,e_4)$ by adding and substracting from $\{v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ where $v_3=e_4$ and $v_4=e_1$.

However, it is not specified that $4$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $V$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that $v_1=(1,1,-1,0)^t$ and $v_2=(0,0,1,1)^t$ is a base of $V$.  Complete $v_1$ and $v_2$ with $v_3$ and $v_4$  to obtain a base of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then $f=MDM^{-1}$ where $D=\mbox{diag}(0,0,4,4)$ and $M=[v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4]$. Then $\mbox{ker}(f)=V\not=\{0\}$ and the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $4$ is generated by $v_3$ and $v_4$.